# Return from function if execution finished within timeout or make callback otherwise

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a project in Python 3.5 without any usage of asynchronous features. I have to implement the folowing logic:

```
def should_return_in_3_sec(some_serious_job, arguments, finished_callback):
    # Start some_serious_job(*arguments) in a task
    # if it finishes within 3 sec:
    #    return result immediately
    # otherwise return None, but do not terminate task.
    # If the task finishes in 1 minute:
    #    call finished_callback(result)
    # else:
    #    call finished_callback(None)
    pass
```

The function `should_return_in_3_sec()` should remain synchronous, but it is up to me to write any new asynchronous code (including `some_serious_job()`).

What is the most elegant and pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Fork off a thread doing the serious job, let it write its result into a queue and then terminate.  Read in your main thread from that queue with a timeout of three seconds.  If the timeout occurs, start another thread and return None.  Let the second thread read from the queue with a timeout of one minute; if that timeouts also, call finished_callback(None); otherwise call finished_callback(result).

I sketched it like this:

```
import threading, queue

def should_return_in_3_sec(some_serious_job, arguments, finished_callback):
  result_queue = queue.Queue(1)

  def do_serious_job_and_deliver_result():
    result = some_serious_job(arguments)
    result_queue.put(result)

  threading.Thread(target=do_serious_job_and_deliver_result).start()

  try:
    result = result_queue.get(timeout=3)
  except queue.Empty:  # timeout?

    def expect_and_handle_late_result():
      try:
        result = result_queue.get(timeout=60)
      except queue.Empty:
        finished_callback(None)
      else:
        finished_callback(result)

    threading.Thread(target=expect_and_handle_late_result).start()
    return None
  else:
    return result
```

Comment: Nice! Though I did not find termination of serious_job on later timeout... I aslo wonder, is it OK to use standard `queue` in this multithreaded example?

Comment: The `queue` module is meant for threaded contexts, yes.  It explicitly synchronizes its use.  And you of course have a slight issue (depends on your context if it actually will become a problem) with terminating the split-off threads.  But the specs as you gave them did not allow for a proper joining them again.

Answer (score 1):

The `threading` module has some simple timeout options, see `Thread.join(timeout)` for example.

If you do choose to use asyncio, below is a a partial solution to address some of your needs:

```
import asyncio

import time


async def late_response(task, flag, timeout, callback):
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([task], timeout=timeout)
    callback(done.pop().result() if done else None)  # will raise an exception if some_serious_job failed
    flag[0] = True  # signal some_serious_job to stop
    return await task


async def launch_job(loop, some_serious_job, arguments, finished_callback,
                     timeout_1=3, timeout_2=5):
    flag = [False]
    task = loop.run_in_executor(None, some_serious_job, flag, *arguments)
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([task], timeout=timeout_1)
    if done:
        return done.pop().result()  # will raise an exception if some_serious_job failed
    asyncio.ensure_future(
        late_response(task, flag, timeout_2, finished_callback))
    return None


def f(flag, n):
    for i in range(n):
        print("serious", i, flag)
        if flag[0]:
            return "CANCELLED"
        time.sleep(1)
    return "OK"


def finished(result):
    print("FINISHED", result)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result = loop.run_until_complete(launch_job(loop, f, [1], finished))
print("result:", result)
loop.run_forever()
```

This will run the job in a separate thread (Use `loop.set_executor(ProcessPoolExecutor())` to run a CPU intensive task in a process instead).  Keep in mind it is a bad practice to terminate a process/thread - the code above uses a very simple list to signal the thread to stop (See also `threading.Event` / `multiprocessing.Event`).

While implementing your solution, you might discover you would want to modify your existing code to use couroutines instead of using threads.